# Usage of gitlab API for user snippets

Tags: gitlab, code-snippets

Im currently trying to write a little addin for my IDE so i can create snippets on my gitlab. I have checked the API and it seems its possible to create snippets associated with a project using `/api/v3/project/id/snippet` and the according POST parameters. However I dont really want to associate the snippets with a particular project and in the web interface its possible to choose "My Snippets" and when you create a snippet there you dont have to attribute it to a project. I wonder if there is also an API to create a snippet thats not linked to a project but rather to my account?

Also according to https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/doc/api/project_snippets.md#create-new-snippet its not possible to choose the visibility of the snippet while in the web interface you can chosse private, public or internal. Is there something else? Is the API out of date? Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is the use of snippets in gitlab?

Comment: Single files that you don't want to create a repository for. Like GitHub gists, except lame :(

Answer (score 1):

There is no REST API to change or view user snippets.

To set visibility, you can use attribute `visibility_level` (although undocumented, [it is actually required](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/lib/api/project_snippets.rb#L50)). It uses [the same level numbers as projects](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/doc/api/projects.md#project-visibility-level).

Comment: can you please elaborate? I have no idea what you mean by "you can use attribute visibility_level." Is it really possible that GitLab snippets are this crippled? The only other option is to create a repository for one file, and then be stuck with that file having to live inside a folder. Any sort of "rawgit" equivalent for GitLab?